# Loop Database Table and disply in TextBox SQL, VB.NET

Tags: sql, vb.net

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
           If Integer.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, val) Then
            If val >= 10 Then
                Timer1.Stop()
                MsgBox("The End")
            Else
                TextBox1.Text = (val + 1).ToString
            End If
        Else
            TextBox1.Text = "1"
        End If
    End Using
End Sub
```

In this code textbox1 showing 1 to 10 numbers. When I'm looping database its showing only first value. I want to display all loop values into textbox1.

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
          Dim val As Integer
    Dim connect As String = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\nagaraju\Documents\Attendance.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(connect)
        Dim query As String = "SELECT ID FROM studentdata where Class=@Class"
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(query, conn)
        'cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", TextBox1.Text)
        cmd.Parameters("@ID").Value = TextBox1.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@class", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = ComboBox1.SelectedItem
        Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        adapter.Fill(dt)
        If Integer.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, val) Then
            If val <= dt.Rows.Count Then
                Timer1.Stop()
                MsgBox("The End")
            Else
                TextBox1.Text = (val + 1).ToString
            End If
        Else
            TextBox1.Text = dt.Rows(0)(0)
        End If
    End Using
End Sub
```

In this code I tried to loop database values, but didn't work its showing Error: "An SqlParameter with ParameterName '@ID' is not contained by this SqlParameterCollection". Please have a look to solve my Issue. Thank you...

Comment: There are two main reasons that beginners have trouble solving problems. Firstly, they try to solve multiple problems as though they were one. Secondly, they expect to be able to write code without actually knowing what it has to do. You're doing the second here. You know the result you want but you haven't actually thought about thew logic required to achieve that result. You need to spend some time working out that logic first, then write code to explicitly implement that logic. At the moment, every `Tick` you execute the same query and always use the first row. How does that make sense?

Comment: @jmcilhinney, Thank you for response, I tried so many ways to solve this issue, but I couldn't handle this problem. Once have a look on my issue to solve my problem. Thank you

Comment: If you can't explain the specific logic that you're trying to implement then you shouldn't be writing any code yet. What is the logic? Based on your code, I doubt you know, so it's no wonder you can't write code to do it.

Comment: @jmcilhinney,  "If val >= dt.Rows.Count Then" I changed to "If val <= dt.Rows.Count Then" It's working after changing code. But its showing all values from database table I want to display combobox selected item values. Could you give me any example on this issue. Thank you...